# Updated version of PHP/Curl and now program is not working anymore (SSL)

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have written a little program in PHP with Curl and it was working fine with version of curl 7.21. I have updated my PHP and now using curl 7.26. Unfortunately, now the server I am trying to access replies (header): HTTP/1.1 501 Method POST is not defined in RFC 2068 and is not supported by the Servlet API. Before, with Curl 7.21, it was replying (header) OK and everything was working.

Please help as this is driving me crazy :(...

Here is the code to access the other server:

```
function authenticateihc($username,$password,$ihcip,$timeout,$debug=0)
{
 if (cURLcheckBasicFunctions())
 {
   // Definition of XML request according to IHC standards
   $xml_request  = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n";
   $xml_request .= "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\n";
   $xml_request .= "<SOAP-ENV:Body>\n";
   $xml_request .= "<ns1:authenticate1 xmlns:ns1=\"utcs\" xsi:type=\"ns1:WSAuthenticationData\">\n"; 
   $xml_request .= "<ns1:password xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">".$password."</ns1:password>\n";
   $xml_request .= "<ns1:username xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">".$username."</ns1:username>\n";  
   $xml_request .= "<ns1:application xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">treeview</ns1:application>\n";
   $xml_request .= "</ns1:authenticate1>\n";
   $xml_request .= "</SOAP-ENV:Body>\n";
   $xml_request .= "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>\n";

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_request);
   // Forcer cURL à utiliser un nouveau cookie de session 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$ihcip.'/ws/AuthenticationService');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 

   // Si l'URL est en HTTPS 
   if (preg_match('`^https://`i', $ihcip))
   { 
    // Ne pas vérifier la validité du certificat SSL 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
   } 

   if ($debug == 1) {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'dbg_curl_data');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'dbg_curl_data');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
   }

   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   $info = curl_getinfo($ch);


   if ($debug == 1) 
   {
      echo '<fieldset><legend>request headers</legend> <pre>', htmlspecialchars(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)), '</pre> </fieldset>';
      echo '<fieldset><legend>xml request</legend> <pre>', htmlspecialchars($xml_request), '</pre> </fieldset>';
      echo '<fieldset><legend>response</legend> <pre>', htmlspecialchars(dbg_curl_data(null)), '</pre> </fieldset>';
      echo '<fieldset><legend>curl info</legend> <pre>error: ' . curl_error($ch).'<BR>';
      echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'].'<BR></pre> </fieldset>';
   }

   if ($debug == 2) 
   {
       echo '<fieldset><legend>Variable</legend> <pre>', htmlspecialchars($result), '</pre> </fieldset>';
   }

   $result_from_xml = array (
    "loginSuccessful" => get_string_between($result, '<ns1:loginWasSuccessful xsi:type="xsd:boolean">' , '</ns1:loginWasSuccessful'),
    "AccountInvalid" => get_string_between($result, '<ns1:loginFailedDueToAccountInvalid xsi:type="xsd:boolean">' , '</ns1:loginFailedDueToAccountInvalid'),
    "InsufficientRights" => get_string_between($result, '<ns1:loginFailedDueToInsufficientUserRights xsi:type="xsd:boolean">' , '</ns1:loginFailedDueToInsufficientUserRights')
   );

   curl_close($ch);
   return $result_from_xml;
 }
 else 
 {
     echo "Error<br>";
     echo "_____<br>";
     echo "Curl installed on this computer: ".cURLcheckBasicFunctions()."<br>";
 }
}

function cURLcheckBasicFunctions() 
{ 
  if( !function_exists("curl_init") && 
      !function_exists("curl_setopt") && 
      !function_exists("curl_exec") && 
      !function_exists("curl_close") ) return false; 
  else return true; 
} 

function dbg_curl_data($curl, $data=null) {
  static $buffer = '';

  if ( is_null($curl) ) {
    $r = $buffer;
    $buffer = '';
    return $r;
  }
  else {
    $buffer .= $data;
    return strlen($data);
  }
}

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);   
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
```